# How to commit modifided files & folder in one command using git?

Tags: git, command, commit, directory

I have tried below but seems not working

```
$ git commit -m "Changes" vendor/* dev/* .htaccess composer.json
```

Error

```
error: pathspec 'vendor/cweagans' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'vendor/magefan' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'vendor/phpoffice' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

I have multiple folders modified with files.

How to commit all using one command?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `git add` command to add new (or changed) files to the staging area before using `git commit`.

Comment: From local i need to push changes & on server need to pull. `git add` will add files right? I have modified files in multiple folders & single files as well as mentioned in question

Comment: Ankit, I am not sure what you are asking, or perhaps you are confused about how git works.  The `add` and `commit `commands work on the _local_ repository (see https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes).  Git `push` and `pull` sync with the central repository (https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/syncing).  As Greg says, you use `add` to tell git that you want to `commit` a file to the _local_ repository, and when you think the code is ready to share, you use `push` to move already `commit`ed code up to the central repository.

Answer (score 0):

Commit *specified* files in one command with [`--include`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#git-commit---include).

```
$ git commit -m "Some commit message" --include <path1> <path2> <pathN>
```

Commit *all* modified and deleted files in one command with [`--all`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#git-commit---all).

```
$ git commit -m "Some commit message" --all
```

For the example in your question `--include` looks like this:

```
$ git commit -m "Changes" --include vendor/* dev/* .htaccess composer.json
```